# Nested for loop issue in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

> Input JSON:

```
{
   "parent":[
      {
         "parentId":"111",
         "children":[
            {
               "child":"child1",
               "childName":"ABCDE"
            },
            {
               "childSchool":"XYZ School",
               "childClass":"fourth"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "parentId":"222",
         "children":[
            {
               "child":"child1",
               "childName":"FGHI"
            },
            {
               "childSchool":"XYZ School",
               "childClass":"fourth"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "parentId":"333",
         "children":[
            {
               "child":"child1",
               "childName":"BBB"
            },
            {
               "childSchool":"XYZ School",
               "childClass":"fifth"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Using JavaScript i need following output. I tried to loop through parent array using 2 for loop (i and i+1), and compare the childSchool field , if it is same then append childName as 1 string as shown in output(ABC*, FGH*) and the item not matching will be separate array. But this solution is not working. Can someone help?

OutPut:

```
{
   "parent":[
      {
         "parentId":"111",
         "children":[
            {
               "child":"child1",
               "childName":"ABC*, FGH*" // <==== expected output
            },
            {
               "childSchool":"XYZ School",
               "childClass":"fourth"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "parentId":"333",
         "children":[
            {
               "child":"child1",
               "childName":"BBB"
            },
            {
               "childSchool":"XYZ School",
               "childClass":"fifth"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}

for(let i=0; i<parent.length; i++) {
  for(let j=i+1; j<parent.length; j++) {
   for(let child of parent[i].children) {
   for(let chd of parent[j].children) {
      if(child.childSchool === 'XYZ School' && chd.childSchool === 'XYZ School' && child.childClass === 'fourth && chd.childClass === 'fourth') {
           sameSchoolGrade = true;
             childName=child.childName + ',' + chd.childName;
         }
  
     }
       if(sameSchoolGrade) {
         //trying to assign to response obj 
         }
          }
    }}
```

Comment: this isn't really a TypeScript problem, its more of a JavaScript problem, so I've edited your question to reflect that.

Comment: Also, can you post the actual code you've tried, rather than describing it?

Comment: added code snippet @BenWainwright

Answer (score 0):

it's a strange Json, generally the arrays should be the same properties,

You can get it in two pass, first a loop over the array search is there're a node with the conditions, after filter the data.

```
  this.data.parent.forEach(x=>{

    //try to find a node with same childSchool and childClass
    //see that childSchool and childClass is under children[1].childSchool and children[1].ChildClass

    const node=this.data.parent.find(i=>i.children[1].childSchool==x.children[1].childSchool &&
           i.children[1].childClass==x.children[1].childClass)

    //if it's not the same
    if (node!=x)
    {
      //add to childName the childName
      node.children[0].childName+=","+x.children[0].childName

      //equal the childName to ""
      x.children[0].childName="";
    }
  })
  //filter and get only the childName has a value
  this.data.parent=this.data.parent.filter(x=>x.children[0].childName)
```